# Selenium: How to make the web driver to wait for page to refresh before executing another test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing Test Cases using Selenium web Driver in TestNG and I have a scenario where I am running multiple tests sequentially (refer below)

```
@Test(priority =1)
public void Test1(){
}
@Test(priority =2)
public void Test2(){ 
}
```

Both Tests are AJAX calls where a Dialog box opens, tests executes, then dialog box closes and then a notification message appears on top of page and **after each successful test the page refreshes**.

**The problem is:** Test2 do not wait for the page to refresh/reload. Suppose when Test1 gets successfully completed, Test2 will start before page refresh (ie it opens the dialog box, executes scenarios etc..) meanwhile the page refreshes (which was bound to happen after successful execution of Test1 ). Now since the page refreshes, the diaog box opened due to Test2 is no longer present and then Test2 fails.

(Also, I do not know how long it will take to refresh the page. Therefore, **I do not want to use Thread.sleep(xxxx) before executing Test2**)

Also, I don't think

```
driver.navigate().refresh()
```

will solve my problem by putting it before Test2 as in that case my page will get refreshed twice. The problem is the refresh that is happening through the code (which is uncertain as it may take 1 sec or 3 sec or 5 sec)

Comment: I have a similar scenario - indeterminate loading until a confirmation dialog asks to continue - no page refresh. Web page is already loaded - it is processing ajax. Want to confirm that dialog shows up.

Comment: General question about the scope of a test: Isn't the successful reload part of your test? I would assume it is, so I would end test #1 with a check whether the page reloaded, and then test #2 doesn't even have that problem to begin with, as the problem is handled at the end of test #1 (or in the @AfterMethod if you don't care about the outcome / don't see it to be part of the test really)

Answer (score 22):

If you are waiting for element to present then

In selenium rc we used to do this using `selenium.WaitForCondition("selenium.isElementPresent(\"fContent\")", "desiredTimeoutInMilisec")`

In web driver U can achieve the same thing using this

```
WebDriverWait myWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 45);
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> conditionToCheck = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
{
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
        return (input.findElements(By.id("fContent")).size() > 0);
    }
};
myWait.until(conditionToCheck);
```

This way you can wait for your element to be present before executing your test2.

**UPDATED :**

If you are waiting for page to load then in web driver you can use this code:

```
public void waitForPageLoaded(WebDriver driver)
{
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new
ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() 
    {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver)
        {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    try
    {
        wait.until(expectation);
    }
    catch(Throwable error)
    {
        assertFalse("Timeout waiting for Page Load Request to complete.",true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to wait for the element to appear. I want to wait for the page to reload/refresh and then only I want to execute Test2

Comment: As per question I suppose that after executing your test1 the page get refreshed and therefore you cant get the desired element on which the test case 2 is executed.

Comment: No. Both tests are independent on each other. If I run both tests individually, they get successfully executed.

Comment: Any ways you can also use WebDriverBackedSelenium for access to the function selenium.waitForPageToLoad("timeout"); That will also serve your purpose for waiting for page to load.For doing this in web driver see the updated answer.

Comment: Your **waitForPageLoaded** method is great!! thank you @Abhi_Mishra

Comment: problem is, if you are waiting for a page to refresh then you can't wait for elements - because they are already on the page

Comment: @Tyler : Yeah waiting for elements is useful when you are working with ajax applications or you don't want to wait for complete page load.

Comment: I don't see the need of waitForPageLoaded. As far as I know WebDriver blocks until the page is loaded, automatically.

Comment: But elements are often not in final place when WebDriver continues. Thus they are loaded but can't be clicked.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic - whether or not the WebDriver blocks depends on which concrete driver is in use.  For example, I have found in my experience that ChromeDriver does block, whilst FirefoxDriver does not.

Comment: The waitForPageLoaded(WebDriver webdriver) function worked perfectly in my case! thanks alot

Answer (score 16):

[Here](http://automationoverflow.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/waiting-for-page-load-to-complete/) is better and tested version of `WaitForPageLoad` implementation in C#.Net

```cs
public void WaitForPageLoad(int maxWaitTimeInSeconds) {
    string state = string.Empty;
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxWaitTimeInSeconds));

        //Checks every 500 ms whether predicate returns true if returns exit otherwise keep trying till it returns ture
        wait.Until(d = > {

            try {
                state = ((IJavaScriptExecutor) _driver).ExecuteScript(@"return document.readyState").ToString();
            } catch (InvalidOperationException) {
                //Ignore
            } catch (NoSuchWindowException) {
                //when popup is closed, switch to last windows
                _driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles.Last());
            }
            //In IE7 there are chances we may get state as loaded instead of complete
            return (state.Equals("complete", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || state.Equals("loaded", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        });
    } catch (TimeoutException) {
        //sometimes Page remains in Interactive mode and never becomes Complete, then we can still try to access the controls
        if (!state.Equals("interactive", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            throw;
    } catch (NullReferenceException) {
        //sometimes Page remains in Interactive mode and never becomes Complete, then we can still try to access the controls
        if (!state.Equals("interactive", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            throw;
    } catch (WebDriverException) {
        if (_driver.WindowHandles.Count == 1) {
            _driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles[0]);
        }
        state = ((IJavaScriptExecutor) _driver).ExecuteScript(@"return document.readyState").ToString();
        if (!(state.Equals("complete", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || state.Equals("loaded", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this look like in ruby?

Comment: Brilliant! It does not matter if the IWebElemt::click() leads to HTML or Javascript. This solution works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you could trigger a URL change this would work:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(yourDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlContains("/url-fragment"));
```