# Automated tests with Selenium: how to close alert-Windows?

Tags: multithreading, selenium, alert

Excecuting an automated test on a website with selenium I was faced with this problem, that somewhere on the website, when my test changes the selection of a DropDownList, an alert-window is thrown asking "are you sure you want to leave this page".

The root problem is the refreshing times of the page. When I look for an element:

```
Select sortingDropDownlist= new Select(webdriver.findElement(By.id("sortView")));
```

it takes some time for the page to be refreshed, even if I hav not changed anything. In this case a thread.sleep(500) would help preventing an alert to be poped out.

After a change to the DropDownList: 
    sortingDropDownlist.selectByValue("alpha");

the onchange-javascript behind the list tries to reload the page, while my test is continuing to the Then-part verificating the new value. The test stucks there until someone manually closes the alert window. I get the error:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
 from unexpected alert open
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
 Command duration or timeout: 43 milliseconds
 Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
 System info: host: 'de-adn-bfxqp72', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
 Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4), userDataDir=C:\Users\javadieh\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir11488_27974}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=53.0.2785.116, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
  Session ID: b6e2d6fec84269128a420809f929916d
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  ...
```

An easy but dirty solution is again to Thread.sleep(500) directly after changing the selection. But I have a bad feeling using thread.sleep. So I am looking for a good solution.

I also tried this solution: in a seperate thread waiting for an alert window to appear, switch to it and close it.
But... although the alert window ist there my thread does not find it. It is not a matter of time out. Here ist my thread's code:

```
public class AlertChecker extends Thread {
  WebDriver webdriver=null;
  WebDriverWait wait;

public AlertChecker(WebDriver webdriver) {
        super();
        this.webdriver = webdriver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10);
  }

  public void run(){
    System.out.println("MyThread running");
      try {
           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
           System.out.println("alert found");
           Alert alert = webdriver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.accept();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          //exception handling
        System.out.println(e);
      }
      System.out.println("MyThread stopping");
 }
```

}

How can I wait for the page to be refreshed?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the console output? Is "MyThread stopping" printed to out?

Comment: After I close the alert window (after 10 seconds) I get:     org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for alert to be present
...
MyThread stopping

Comment: Are you sure, you are waiting for javascript alert??

Comment: Actaully I found this wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());   in some entries here and used it. I hoped it is waiting for javascript alert??

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a `JavaScript Alert` please use the below code.

```
  public static void isAlertpresent(WebDriver driver)
  {
      try
      {
          Alert window = driver.switchTo().alert();
          String content = window.getText();
          window.accept();
          System.out.println("Alert Appeared & handeled : "+content );
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {

          System.out.println("No Alert Appeared");

      } 
}
```

call this method from where you suspect the `Alert` is appearing as below,

```
isAlertpresent(driver);
```

If its not a `JavaScript Alert`, try `Window handling` techniques to handle the alert.

Comment: following your sujestion I get the error added above at the end of my question(In part: Further information) i.e.     org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unexpected alert open

Comment: can you figure out at which part of your execution this alert appears

Comment: I just added it to the question declaration above. Thanks

Comment: my mistake, sorry. call the `isAlertpresent(driver);` after that dropdown value change. did you tried that

Comment: Yes, actually I call it before and after. As it is a synchron function it just happens accidentally to catch the alert. Doesn't it?

Comment: When that function is called it looks for any active `JavaScript Alert`. If any alert is present it handles it. If it does't come across any active alert then it allows the next sentence to execute. Its not a accidental catch method.

Comment: After that Dropdown change how long you waited before calling this alert handle method

Comment: How can I wait for page reloading in selenium?

Comment: Following this suggestion for page loading: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244225/selenium-how-to-make-the-web-driver-to-wait-for-page-to-refresh-before-executin) it didn't help eigther.

Comment: You can use `Thread.Sleep` by assuming an approximate time for the page load.