# Selenium: finding the right element identifier

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm relatively new to selenium automation, and am trying to test a form that has been created for me. I'd like to put test values into a textbox whose HTML code looks like:

```
<input type="text" id="txtEndCustId" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" class="Text" required="" onfocus="txtEndCustIdFocus('Your customer END CUSTOMER DEP ID');" onblur="txtEndCustIdblur();">
```

I thought I'd use the "id" of the box, but the code:

```
Dim options As New Chrome.ChromeOptions
Dim service As ChromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService

Dim wd As New Chrome.ChromeDriver(service, options)

wd.Navigate.GoToUrl("x")
wd.FindElementById("txtEndCustId").SendKeys("1")
```

Gives an error:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"txtEndCustId"}
```

To be perfectly honest I've no idea where I went wrong here - thanks in advance for your help.

Is there any "List All Element ids" function, so that I can marry them up with what's shown in the chrome inspector view?

Comment: Please provide the entire line of code where you are trying to get the element by it's ID, (...) does not give enough information.

Comment: Sorry, it's just the chromedriver object - I've expanded the sample code now

Comment: IS it possible you are trying to get the element before the page has fully loaded?? You may want to read this SO post on how to do a wait with webdriver (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244225/selenium-how-to-make-the-web-driver-to-wait-for-page-to-refresh-before-executin)

Comment: no, I'm stepping through the code in the debugger, and it doesn't even allow me to step to that line before the page has finished the 'navigate' line and fully loaded - or at least it appears visually to be fully loaded, and the chromium window can see the element if I hit F12 there.

Comment: @MartingKS is the element you want wrapped inside a frame, iframe?

Comment: yes! Sorry, new to this F12 view and thought they were all div's I've got `<iframe id="ctl00_CPH_iframeCat" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="overflow: auto; min-height: 2000px; height: 2100px; width: 1280px;" src="xx">
        </iframe>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your element is inside a frame, you need to navigate the driver to the frame first, a frame has it's own Document containing x number of DOM elements.

First switch to the frame:

```
//You need to use method switchTo() to set the driver to the frame document
//In this case we are passing in the id of the iframe
wd.switchTo().frame("ctl00_CPH_iframeCat");

//Now that the driver is working on the frame document, you should be able to manipulate the
//input you want
wd.FindElementById("txtEndCustId").SendKeys("1")

//Finally, switch the driver back to the main page document (original document which contains the frames)
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Here is a good piece of documentation which should explain this in more detail:
(http://www.assertselenium.com/webdriver/handling-iframes-using-webdriver/)